# Google Cloud Platform Shared VPC page - insufficient permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm running into a weird issue in GCP where as a project owner and network admin, I am unable to access the Shared VPC page from within the GCP VPC menu. I'm under the impression I need to add the compute.XPNAdmin role (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shared-vpc/#iam_in_shared_vpc) but I also don't see that role as an option in IAM.

I was able to access the Shared VPC page at least a few months ago, and I don't think there's been any changes to our IAM setup in that time.

Seems as if some permissions are missing from the GCP console, and I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get ‘Compute Shared VPC Admin’ role. At the organization level, this role can only be granted by an organization admin.

see this doc for reference:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles

Answer (score 1):

You need to be owner of the Organization (not just the project) to create the Shared VPC or have the owner give you the proper access via IAM. Basically they're the only user allowed to start this process.

Answer (score 1):

To setup the shared VPC admin , you need to have organization administrator role and organization policy administrator role

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need `Compute Shared VPC Admin` role to configure shared VPC.